# Can't load from Oracle when Id is Guid in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, guid

We're saving an object to NHibernate where the Id is typed Guid.  Based on other things we've found we have this as a type char(36).

- We create an object and save it via NHibernate.  This works fine and we see `64599239BB0C1C48B44C36D9F9267830` in the column.
- When we then try to load using a guid we don't get any results and NHibernate Profiler shows that the `WHERE` clause is looking for `0x64599239BB0C1C48B44C36D9F9267830`  which isn't matching.

Obviously we're doing something wrong.. so any ideas what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data type on the database should be `RAW`, and of `16` length. This is what trying to recreate the database using NHibernate produces.