# I can't get any data from my database using NHibernate sessionfactory object in ASP.Net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, configuration, sessionfactory

I have checked that I can connect and get data from the DB using regular C#, which I can. However, when I try to extract data from my DB via session/ sessionfactory, I get nothing.  I am a newbie and I suspect this is an easy fix for a seasoned professional, but I have been researching and am at a loss. Here is my code: (in hibernate.cfg.xml, the server name, username, and password are changed for privacy reasons):

### hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
  <session-factory >
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.OracleClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=NAME;User Id=USERID;Password=USERID;Integrated Security=no;</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

### EnumsTable.hbc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="DataTransfers" namespace="DataTransfers">
<class name="DataTransfers.EnumsTable, DataTransfers"  table="TIME_LOG_ENUMS" >
<id column="ENUM_ID_PK" name="ENUM_ID_PK" type="Byte[]" unsaved-value="0">
<generator class="native"></generator>
</id>
<property name="ENUM_NAME" column="ENUM_NAME" type="string" length="100" not-null="false"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

### EnumsTable.cs

```
namespace DataTransfers
{
public class EnumsTable
{
private Byte[] enum_id_pk {get; set;}
private string enum_name { get; set;}
}
}
```

### Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                    <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                    <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate"/>
                </sectionGroup>
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="DATA_SOURCE" value="serverName"/>
        <add key="PROVIDER" value="NONE"/>
        <add key="DBTYPE" value="Oracle"/>
        <add key="PERFORMANCE" value="High"/>
        <add key="PASSWORD" value="password"/>
        <add key="USERID" value="username"/>
        <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-AutoStart" value="true"/>
        <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Sleep" value="60000"/>
        <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Age" value="120000"/>
    </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>
        <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
        <compilation debug="true">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
        <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
            </compiler>
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules>
            <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
            <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
            <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

### Default.aspx.cs

```
namespace PresentationLayer
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                //open a session
                NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration config = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
                config.Configure();
                //config.AddAssembly("DataTransfers");
                ISessionFactory sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
                ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
                IList enumIds = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(EnumsTable)).List();
                ddlEnumsIds.DataSource = enumIds;
                ddlEnumsIds.DataTextField = "enum_name";
                ddlEnumsIds.DataValueField = "enum_id_pk";
                ddlEnumsIds.DataBind();
                session.Close();

            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add that I am not getting any errors.  I simply get no data.

Comment: I also realized that I needed a <mapping> tag in the hibernate.cfg.xml file and am now getting a new error.

Comment: You definitely don't want to open a new session every time the page loads, this should be done on `Application_Start`.  Also, you might want to check out [Castle ActiveRecord](http://docs.castleproject.org/Active%20Record.MainPage.ashx) which makes configuring and working with NHibernate *much* easier..

Comment: You should put the `SessionFactory` in a global class. It is a huge performance hit to build the session factory on every page load. Also, is a Byte Array really the data type for your key?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  @origin I'm not 100% on the Byte array but the oracle datatype is raw as its a sys_guid() column and I found a conversion that said it was a byte array.

Comment: You should provide the error. This question shows the GUID being used as a string (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494669/cant-load-from-oracle-when-id-is-guid-in-nhibernate). Also, you should use the `ShowSQL` flag or NHibernate Profiler to show you the SQL query being generated. This often provides invaluable information as to why things aren't going as expected.

Comment: Did find that I forgot to add the <mapping> tag to the hibernate.cfg.xml.  Now I get new errors and all sorts of other problems.  thanks for all your help. Sorry, it has too many problems to sum up in one answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your xml doesn't seem to contain any nhibernate configuration information.  There's no provider information or connection information that I can see.  The config section should look like this

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.provider">
        NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
      </property>
      <property name="dialect">
        NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle10gDialect
      </property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">
        NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver
      </property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">
        User Id=oe;
        Password=oe;
        Data Source=YOUR_TNS;
        Pooling=true;
        Enlist=false;
        Statement Cache Size=50;
        Min Pool Size=10;
        Incr Pool Size=5;
        Decr Pool Size=2;
      </property>
      <property name="show_sql">
        true
      </property>
      <mapping assembly="NhbHelper"/>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

One of the nice things with the newer version of NHibernate are the loqacious mapping and fluent configuration.  it makes spinning up NHibernate a breeze.  That code looks like this

```
        Configure = new Configuration();
    Configure.SessionFactoryName(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionFactoryName"]);
        Configure.DataBaseIntegration(db =>
                                      {
                                        db.Dialect<Oracle10gDialect>();
                                        db.Driver<OracleDataClientDriver>();
                                        db.KeywordsAutoImport = Hbm2DDLKeyWords.AutoQuote;
                                        db.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
                                        db.ConnectionStringName = System.Environment.MachineName;
                                        db.BatchSize = 20;
                                        db.Timeout = 10;
                                        db.HqlToSqlSubstitutions = "true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'";
                                      });
    Configure.SessionFactory().GenerateStatistics();

        Map();
```

Also look at the Oracle dialect.  Guids are supported in Oracle as RAW(16).  So it looks like you need to change your mapping for that field.